# CURL command getting failed in jenkins

Tags: curl, jenkins, jira

I'm trying to run the following command in jenkins pipeline code

def response="curl -D- -u 'AAA:AAA' -X POST -H 'X-Atlassian-Token:nocheck' -F 'file=@${workspace}\test.txt' http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/AAA-98/
attachments"
println response
bat "${response}"

getting following error,

def response="curl -D- -u 'AAA:AAA' -X POST -H 'X-Atlassian-Token:nocheck' -F 'file=@${workspace}\test.txt' http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/AAA-98/attachments"
println response
bat "${response}"

d:\jenkins\workspace\My>curl -D- -u 'AAA:AAA' -X POST -H 'X-Atlassian-Token:nocheck' -F 'file=@d:\jenkins\workspace\My  est.txt' http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/AAA-98/attachments 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: est.txt'

100   155    0     0    0   155      0   9687 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  9687
curl: (26) read function returned funny value

Comment: "file=@d:\jenkins\workspace\My est.txt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the `\t` inside `@${workspace}\test.txt`.

The correct one should be `@${workspace}\\test.txt`